# using app script is there a way to move files to containing the same name of a folder to that matching folder

Tags: google-apps-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIw6c.jpg)Please refer to the attached screenshot.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIw6c.jpg)
I want to move files to a folder having the matching name as folder.
Here, if you can see files(ABC1 and testABC2 ) should be moved to folder ABC similarly, file 123xyz should get moved to folder xyz.
guys please suggest me the correct approach and the script.

```
`function MoveFiles(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui   = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ssid = ss.getId();
  var ssparents = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents().next();
  Logger.log('1.parent folder-'+ssparents);


//  var files = ssparents.getFiles();


//-------------------------
    var folderIterator = ssparents.getFolders();
    for (var k =1; folderIterator.hasNext(); k++)
    {

       var folder = folderIterator.next().toString();
            Logger.log('----------------------------------------- ');
            Logger.log('------FOLDER NAME USING FOR LOOP. '+k+' - '+folder);

            var filesIterator = ssparents.getFiles();
            for ( var i = 0;filesIterator.hasNext();i++)         /*to check files in parent folder */
            {

//                Logger.log('2.'+i+' - '+file4+ ' checking for folder- '+ folder);
//                var param= " title contains '"+folder+"' ";
                var checkFileName = ssparents.searchFiles(" title contains '"+folder+"' ");
                for  (var j=0; checkFileName.hasNext();j++) 
                {
                  var file2 = checkFileName.next().getName();
                  var check= filesIterator.next().toString();
                  Logger.log(check+'-------'+file2+'-value of checkFileName '+folder);
                }                
            }
    }

/*  // addding files to other folder and removing fromthe base folder
//    row.toString().match(item) == item //file.toString().match(ssparents)

    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById('1U8_0NT4h1QRy00eJHAFaH9mKmsVptaz9');
    Logger.log('4. check - '+ destination)
    destination.addFile(file);
    var pull = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
    pull.removeFile(
    file);


enter code here

  }
 */ 
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}`

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmrbM.png
```

Answer (score 0):

[Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms) specifies:

> The contains operator only performs prefix matching for a title. For
>   example, the title "HelloWorld" would match for title contains 'Hello'
>   but not title contains 'World'.

### This is why you cannot retrieve files such as `testABC2` with the query `searchFiles("title contains 'ABC' ")`

**WORKAROUND**

- You need to list all files in your parent folder
- Retrieve their names
- Compare the files names against the folder name with the method [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

**A sample code snippet based on your script:**

```
function MoveFiles(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui   = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ssid = ss.getId();
  var ssparents = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents().next();
  Logger.log('1.parent folder-'+ssparents);
  var folderIterator = ssparents.getFolders();
  while (folderIterator.hasNext())
  {
    var folder = folderIterator.next();
    Logger.log("folder name: '"+folder.toString()+"' ");
    var filesIterator = ssparents.getFiles();      
    while (filesIterator.hasNext())         //to check files in parent folder 
      {
      var file=filesIterator.next();
      if (file.getName().indexOf(folder) > -1) {
        Logger.log("file "+file.getName()+" found");
        folder.addFile(file);
        ssparents.removeFile(file);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks **@ziganotschka** that was very helpful. in future if I need any guidance I would like to contact you directly. how can I contact you?

Comment: @TejeshDohare: I am glad if my answer was helpful for you and if this is the case, please consider marking it as accepted to increase visibility for other users with similar problems. However, I am only active on Stackoverflow, which is a public forum. I am confident that if in the future you post other questions on stackoverflow - with a good explanation and a code snippet, such as your current question - there will always be users happy to help you out.